# Induced action of cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology

Let us consider a $G$-space $M$ with $M$ topological space and $G$ topological group and let $H^\bullet(M,\mathbb{Z})$ be the singular cohomology with integer coefficients. I would like to ask if the induced action of $G$ on $H^\bullet(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is as follows:

For each $g$ in $G$, we can define a map $\widehat{g}: C^\bullet(M;\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow C^\bullet(M;\mathbb{Z})$ on the singular cochain complex $C^\bullet(M;\mathbb{Z})$ by composition with the map $g: M \rightarrow M$, i.e., $(\widehat{g}\alpha)(\sigma) = \alpha(g^{-1}(\sigma))$ for all singular cochains $\alpha$ and each singular $n$-simplex $\sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow M$ .

This induces a group action of $G$ on the cohomology groups by setting $\widehat{g}[\alpha] = [\widehat{g}\alpha]$, where $[\alpha]$ is the cohomology class of $\alpha$ in $H^\bullet(M;\mathbb{Z})$.

Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: Is this Wikipedia entry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_cohomology relevant for you?

Comment: No, it isn't. The equivariant cohomology is a related subject but it is not what I'm looking for. however, thanks to the advice

Comment: What would count as a reference?  I don't know of a textbook that writes this down, but there are numerous papers where this is used.  By the way, the way I think about it:  for each fixed $g\in G$, the map $M\rightarrow M$ given by applying $g$ is continuous, so induces a map on cohomology in the same way that every other continuous map does.

Comment: Thank you @JasonDeVito, that's the easiest way to look at it. Btw, if you can give the reference of some papers where it is used it would be nice.

Comment: I found a textbook reference (sort of).  In Hatcher's algebraic topology book (Prop 2.29 of my edition).  There, Hatcher defines the degree of a map from $S^n$ to itself in terms of homology.  In proposition 2.29, he proves that the only non-trivial group which can act freely on $S^{2n}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  He does this by inspecting the induced map on homology.

Comment: I am actually having trouble locating a paper where the explicitly mention *what* the induced map on cohomology is.  It's just assumed to be the one in your post....

Comment: @JasonDeVito OP's definition of the induced action on cohomology seems different from the usual map induced by $g$. The induced map doesn't define a group action (unless $G$ is abelian).

Comment: @feynhat: Well, I admit I didn't read his/her definition clearly.  But it seems to me that it *is* a group action, even if $G$ isn't abelian.  On the level of co-chains, given $h,g\in G$, we have $$(\widehat{hg}(\sigma))(\alpha) = \sigma((hg)^{-1}(\alpha) = \sigma(g^{-1} (h^{-1}(\alpha)) = (\hat{g}(\sigma))(h^{-1}(\alpha)) = (\hat{h}(\hat{g}(\sigma)))(\alpha).$$

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, OP's definition is a group action I wasn't talking about that. I was talking about what you wrote in your comment " for each fixed g∈G, the map M→M given by applying g is continuous, so induces a map on cohomology in the same way that every other continuous map does.". This will not be a group action unless G is abelian.

Comment: @feynhat:  Oh, wow.  I have apparently had a misconception for many years.  Thank you for the correction!  I guess what I should have written is that for each fixed $g\in G$, the induced map $M\rightarrow M$ by applying $g$ is a *homeomorphism*, so $g^{-1}$ is continuous and induces a map in the same way that all continuous functions do.